# Select entries that aren't part of a pair in another table

Tags: mysql, sql

```
Tables:

     users            friends
+-------+----+    +-----+-----+    
| name  | id |    | id1 | id2 |
+-------+----+    +-----+-----+
| user1 | 1  |    |  1  |  2  |
+-------+----+    +-----+-----+
| user2 + 2  | 
+-------+----+
```

In my database `id1` in the `friends` table is the dominant column, which means that if `id1 = 1` and `id2 = 2` then `user1` is friends with `user2` but not the other way around.

I'm trying to select all users from the `users` table that don't have `X` as `id1` in `friends`. This is because I don't want `userX` to be able to find friends that he's already added.

Here is my failed attempt:

`SELECT * FROM users LEFT JOIN friends ON users.id != friends.id2 WHERE friends.id1 = X AND users.id != X;`

I added `users.id != X` since we don't want to return the user himself in a search for other users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using `not in()` [(more efficient than `not exists()` in mysql)](https://explainextended.com/2009/09/18/not-in-vs-not-exists-vs-left-join-is-null-mysql/)

```
select *
from users
where id != xi
  and id not in (
  select id.2
  from friends
  where friends.id1 = x
  )
```

using `not exists()`

```
select *
from users
where id != x 
  and not exists (
  select 1
  from friends
  where friends.id1 = x
    and friends.id2 = users.id
  )
```

Comment: Works! Just had to tweak it because it didn't recognize `NOT` keyword, also added `AND users.id != x` at the end.

Comment: @Lolechi That's strange that it wasn't recognizing `not`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an outer join to do that, you attempt went into the right direction:

```
select u.*
from        users u
left join   friends f
on  u.id = f.id2
where f.id1 is null
```

An outer join returns `NULL` for every non-matched item at least.

Comment: Just tried this:
    `SELECT *
    FROM users
    LEFT JOIN friends
    ON users.id = friends.id2
    WHERE friends.id IS null`

Getting error: Unknown column 'friends.id' in 'where clause'

Comment: friends.id1, sorry, typo

Comment: You said use `OUTER JOIN` but your answer uses `LEFT JOIN`? Why is that? It works perfectly either way.

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/outer-join-simplification.html An _outer join_ is everything that is not an _inner join_, so either a _right_ or a _left_ join, both of them are _outer joins_. You can, by the way, say `LEFT OUTER JOIN` instead of `LEFT JOIN`. `LEFT JOIN` is just an abbreviation